# Unable to pass django template variable array through post back to view

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, html-post

I am trying to develop some basic django templates where i initially pass the django template variable which is an array - {{array_list}}. I am able to perform operations on this dtv easily. But I am unable to post this variable back to views.
Eg. I pass {'array_list': [1,2,3,4]}

```
<form action="some_action" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="sort">
    <input type="hidden" name="array_list" value={{array_list}}>
</form>
```

And in views.py:

```
array_list = request.POST['array_list']
return render(request, 'result.html', {'array_list': array_list})
```

But i don't get the full array back to result.html, and i only get [1, as the array_list.

Comment: try to add quotes`''` around `{{array_list}}` in your html. make it like this: `value='{{array_list}}'`.

Comment: thank @NalinDobhal for your input, it worked seamlessly

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can do something like this:

First, use [**`join`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#join) tag to turn that list into comma separated string.

```
<form action="some_action" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="submit" value="sort">
    <input type="hidden" name="array_list" value='{{array_list|join:","}}'>
</form>
```

And get the value in POST request and split it by `,`.

```
array_list = request.POST['array_list'].split(',')
```

Comment: I am using your way of representing value but its giving : join requires 2 arguments, 1 provided.

Comment: Thanks to your answer, i got to know about join and from documentation that you linked, I figured it out. value should be represented as vvalue={{array_list|join:","}}. Maybe, you can change your answer to this as it would be useful.